# How to access values deep inside a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying get the definitions of certain words using this code:

```
import requests

url = requests.get("https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/fish")

a = url.text()

print(a)
```

The link in the above code snippet returns some values like this:

```
[{"word":"fish","phonetics":[{"text":"/fɪʃ/","audio":"https://lex-audio.useremarkable.com/mp3/fish_us_1.mp3"}],"meanings":[{"partOfSpeech":"noun","definitions":[{"definition":"A limbless cold-blooded vertebrate animal with gills and fins and living wholly in water.","example":"the sea is thick with fish"}]},{"partOfSpeech":"intransitive verb","definitions":[{"definition":"Catch or try to catch fish, typically by using a net or hook and line.","synonyms":["go fishing","angle","cast","trawl"],"example":"he was fishing for bluefish"}]}]},{"word":"fish","phonetics":[{"text":"/fɪʃ/","audio":"https://lex-audio.useremarkable.com/mp3/fish_us_1.mp3"}],"meanings":[{"partOfSpeech":"transitive verb","definitions":[{"definition":"Mend or strengthen (a beam, joint, mast, etc.) with a fish."}]},{"partOfSpeech":"noun","definitions":[{"definition":"A flat plate of metal, wood, or another material that is fixed on a beam or across a joint in order to give additional strength, especially on a ship's damaged mast or spar as a temporary repair."}]}]}]
```

Now, I want to get the first definition from the above result. How do I get it?

Comment: What are your search parameters?

Comment: do u want to get all the definitions or just the first one?

Comment: @deadshot: A list of dicts is a list.

Comment: " is there any way to search for specific values in the whole dictionary at once?" no way

Comment: just the first one

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica "values deep inside a python list" deep inside all are dicts not list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex JSON documents and queries to such documents pose a similar problem than manipulating XML documents; One *can* use a custom set of list comprehensions and utility functions, but one *should* use a specialized tool.

To manipulate JSON documents in Python, you may have a look at [jsonpath_ng](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-ng/):

- The item(s) you want to extract are defined using a JSONPath expression, the equivalent of XML's XPath
- You just add / update your JSONPath expression(s) to extract more / new items

In the next example, the JSONPath expressions defined in `QUERIES` are ran one by one on your JSON document:

```
import requests
import jsonpath_ng
import json


URL = 'https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/fish'
QUERIES = {
    'First kind, first meaning, first definition': jsonpath_ng.parse('[0].meanings[0].definitions[0].definition'),
    'All kind, first definitions': jsonpath_ng.parse('[*].meanings[0].definitions[0].definition'),
    'All definitions': jsonpath_ng.parse('[*].meanings[*].definitions[*].definition')
}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jsdata = requests.get(URL).json()
    for name, query in QUERIES.items():
        print(f'--- {name} ---')
        for match in query.find(jsdata):
            print(json.dumps(match.value, indent=2))
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
s = [...]
for i in s:
    print(i['word'],[ k['definition'] for j in i['meanings'] for k in j['definitions']])
```

Comment: This is returning all the definitions. I want to get just this: ['A limbless cold-blooded vertebrate animal with gills and fins and living wholly in water.', 'Catch or try to catch fish, typically by using a net or hook and line.'], which is the first definition.

Comment: like this?  ` print(s[0]['word'],[ k['definition'] for j in s[0]['meanings'] for k in j['definitions']])`